# Объект "влезает" в стену

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть куб, к которому привязано управление с клавиатуры, есть стена. При приближение куба к стене он в неё "влезает", а потом встаёт рядом. Как это можно починить?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject player;

    void Awake () {
        Color col = Color.green;

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = col;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey("up"))
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, 0.1f));

        if (Input.GetKey("down"))
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, -0.1f));

        if (Input.GetKey("right"))
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0));

        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(-0.1f, 0, 0));
    }

}
```

вот код управления кубом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно больше информации: например ваш управляющий код. или может на кубе стандартный контроллер какой-либо нацеплен что на кубе имеется (rigid body, collider и прочее), что на стене есть и прочее. Возможно прикрепить некий скриншот.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дополнил вопрос.

Comment: шаг сетки какой? или если быть точнее положение стены? у вас куб двигается за кадр на 1м, шанс въехать в стену на этом кадре более чем велик, а на следующем кадре коллизии вытолкнут куб наружу
не стоит управлять чем либо задавая позицию, задавайте скорость

Comment: @vik_78, я так и думал что проблема в этом, можете показать как задать движение через скорость или с помощью чего это делать?

Comment: @vik_78 если делаю так  transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 5), то эффект тот же.

Comment: @Антон, к сожелению не подскажу, т.к. не специалист в Unity, работал с PhysX, но это типичная _проблема_ физики. У вашего объекта есть свойстро velocity? попробуйте с ним поиграться
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Comment: @Антон, transform использовать не стоит, он жестко ставит позицию вашего объекта, а задавая скорость позицию будет расчитывать физический движек

Comment: У объектов с RigidBody стоит скорее использовать как раз методы именно этого компонента. Так, например движение будет происходить за счет метода `MovePosition`.... что-то типа `public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    }`

Comment: Также, если ваш объект движется быстро, то, возможно у rigidbody уместно будет поставить `CollissionDetection` → `Continuous` , хотя конечно 0.1f я бы не назвал быстрым)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за ответ, так лучше, хоть и при первом касание стены он всё равно немного в неё "влазит", но хоть не начинает дрожать как перед этим.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но теперь он не движется по диагонали .

Comment: @Антон еще у вас по два BoxCollider на объектах, может это тоже проблема....удалите по одному.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак.

У объектов с `RigidBody` стоит скорее использовать как раз методы именно этого компонента. Так, например движение будет происходить за счет метода [MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html).

Например:

```
public Rigidbody rb;
void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void FixedUpdate() {
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Заметьте, метод **FixedUpdate**. В работают с физикой. Особенно, с классом `Rigidbody`.

Также, если ваш объект движется быстро, то, возможно у `RigidBody` уместно будет поставить `CollissionDetection` → `Continuous (хотя конечно 0.1f я бы не назвал быстрым).

Continuous используется для обнаружения столкновений со статической сеткой геометрии, если ваш предмет движется очень быстро.

По поводу движения, в том числе по диагонали.

Движение обычно приводится к нормализованному вектору (принимает значение от 0 до 1) и на его основе и на основе других параметров (скорость передвижения, дельта) прибавляется к позиции объекта.

В общем кривом случае это выглядит как-то так:

```
public Rigidbody rb;
float moveSpeed = 5.0f;

void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();         
}

void FixedUpdate() {

    Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        move.z = Vector3.forward.z;

    if (Input.GetKey("down"))
        move.z = -Vector3.forward.z;

    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        move.x = Vector3.right.x;

    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        move.x = -Vector3.right.x;

    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + move * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

**Небольшое замечание**: По идее всякие расчеты и нажатия на клавиши надо обрабатывать в `Update`, а вот в применить уже относительно к `RigidBody` надо в `FixedUpdate`

---

В принципе, знаки движения вперед-назад-влево-вправо в *Unity* и можно получить за счет `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` и `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")`, которые принимают значение от -1 до 1, в зависимости от нажатия стрелки ← → (-1/1)  ↓ ↑ (тоже -1/1). Остается значения поместить в вектор, нормализовать его и применить к объекту.

Что-то типа такого:

```
public Rigidbody rb;
float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
private Vector3 inputDirection;

void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();         
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    inputDirection = (new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"))).normalized;
    Vector3 moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(inputDirection); 
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Первый способ работает как надо, а если воспользоваться вторым, то если зажать клавишу на несколько секунд, а затем отпустить, куб прокатиться ещё какое-то расстояние после отжатия клавиши.

Comment: @Антон Все правильно. Потому что движения через rigidBody в принципе основаны на силе трения. Избежать можно конечно сделав первым способом (только чуть покрасивее, не так как я))), также создавать материал для поверхностей и регулировать их силу трения, еще один способ (не знаю на сколько костыльный)  в `Edit` → `Project Settings` → `Input` поставить для эти осей (Horizontal и Vertical) значение `Gravity` побольше, например 50 вместо 3....... все зависит от целей конечно.

Comment: @Антон кстати, небольшое дополнение: По идее всякие расчеты и нажатия на клавиши надо обрабатывать в `Update`, а вот в применить уже относительно к `RigidBody` надо в `FixedUpdate`... имейте это в виду